# echo + single quotes + extraction operator

Tags: shell

I am reading through some help files and the author uses the command
echo '# test line' >> CONTRIBUTING.md

The closest thing that I could find when searching the web was similar syntax to the above but with double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am interested to know what that command does echo '# test line' >> CONTRIBUTING.md